# SP 2013 Administrator Farm getting 403 error on landing page

Tags: 2013, security-token-service

I inherited a SP 2013 On Premises Farm.

I was finishing the migration to Office 365 when the farm started getting me a 403 error.

Earlier this week, there was a change in the PDC FSMO, as well as the old DNS server being disabled.

I've tried changing the Kerberos with no luck.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how should I try to fix this?

Thanks!